# CGAL-4.8.1 Arrangements - Bezier Curves Save Arrangement to File Error

Tags: cgal

I am new to CGAL.

I tried to modify Examples/Arrangement_on_surfaces_2 Bezier_curves.cpp to save arrangement to file as shown below:

```
//! \file examples/Arrangement_on_surface_2/Bezier_curves.cpp
// Constructing an arrangement of Bezier curves.

#include <fstream>

#include <CGAL/basic.h>

#ifndef CGAL_USE_CORE
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Sorry, this example needs CORE ..." << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
#else

#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/CORE_algebraic_number_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Arr_iostream.h>

#include "arr_inexact_construction_segments.h"
#include "arr_print.h"

typedef CGAL::CORE_algebraic_number_traits              Nt_traits;
typedef Nt_traits::Rational                             NT;
typedef Nt_traits::Rational                             Rational;
typedef Nt_traits::Algebraic                            Algebraic;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Rational>                       Rat_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Algebraic>                      Alg_kernel;
typedef Rat_kernel::Point_2                             Rat_point_2;
typedef CGAL::Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2<Rat_kernel, Alg_kernel, Nt_traits>
                                                        Traits_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                               Bezier_curve_2;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits_2>                   Arrangement_2;
//typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits_2>                   Arrangement;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Get the name of the input file from the command line, or use the default
  // Bezier.dat file if no command-line parameters are given.
    const char   *filename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "Bezier.dat";
    const char   *outfilename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "BezierOut.dat";

  // Open the input file.
  std::ifstream   in_file (filename);

  if (! in_file.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open " << filename << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // Read the curves from the input file.
  unsigned int               n_curves;
  std::list<Bezier_curve_2>  curves;
  Bezier_curve_2             B;
  unsigned int               k;

  in_file >> n_curves;
  for (k = 0; k < n_curves; k++) {
    // Read the current curve (specified by its control points).
    in_file >> B;
    curves.push_back (B);

    std::cout << "B = {" << B << "}" << std::endl;
  }
  in_file.close();

  // Construct the arrangement.

  Arrangement_2                   arr;
  insert (arr, curves.begin(), curves.end());

  // Print the arrangement size.
  std::ofstream out_file;
  out_file.open(outfilename);
  out_file << "The arrangement size:" << std::endl
            << "   V = " << arr.number_of_vertices()
            << ",  E = " << arr.number_of_edges() 
            << ",  F = " << arr.number_of_faces() << std::endl;

  out_file << arr;
  out_file.close();

  return 0;
}

#endif
```

If I comment out the line **out_file << arr;** it works fine. Otherwise it generates a C2678 error in `read_x_monotone_curve` in `Arr_text_formtter.h`

I am using Visual Studio 15 x86.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by modifying the print_arrangement(arr) routine in arr_print.h to  save_arrangement(arr) with a std::ofstream in place of std::cout.

It appears that the << operator does not work.

If someone else has a better solution I am open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Points of intersections in an arrangement of Bezier curves cannot be represented in an exact manner.  Therefore, such an arrangement cannot be saved using the default export (<<) operator and the standard format.

The easiest solution is to store the curves, but this means that the arrangement must be recomputed each time the curves are read. Perhaps other solution could be devised, but they are not implemented.